# SQL query: how to remove duplication of Service Charge?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these three table

**ITEM** table:

```
 ITEM_ID    AMOUNT_DUE SERVICE_CHARGE
 -----------------------------------
 1          1000        100
```

**TENDER** table:

```
 ITEM_ID    TYPE_ID  AMOUNT
 -------------------------------
 1          0        600
 1          1        500
```

**TYPE** table:

```
 TYPE_ID    TYPE_NAME
 -------------------------------
 0          CASH
 1          CREDIT
```

I tried:

```
select 
    TYPE_NAME, 
    sum(AMOUNT) as Amount, 
    sum(ServiceCharge) as SC 
from 
    TENDER 
left join
    TYPE on TYPE.TYPE_ID = TENDER.TYPE_ID
left join 
    ITEM on ITEM.ITEM_ID = TENDER.ITEM_ID
group by 
    TYPE_NAME
```

But results have been duplicated for Service Charge like

```
 TYPE_NAME    AMOUNT  SC
 -------------------------------
 CASH         650     100
 CREDIT       500     100
```

NOTE: Service Charge is computed * 10

Comment: Are you summing the `amount` field instead of the `amount_due` field?  If not, I don't understand why you wouldn't get 1000 for the `amount` for each type.  The query you have is doing what you are asking of it.  What are your desired results?

Comment: It appears that the service charge is already rolled up into the `TENDER_TABLE` amounts.  Is this correct?

Comment: Edited Sorry supposed to be Amount

Comment: You still left out your expected results... How should the service charge be divided?  All towards cash or credit or split?

Comment: service charge should be split

Comment: What do you want the results to be?  Your results make perfect sense to me.

Comment: but when service charge is total it would be 200 instead of 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
select TYPE_NAME, sum(AMOUNT) as Amount, 
sum(ServiceCharge)/ (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TENDER.ITEM_ID) ) as SC 
from TENDER 
LEFT JOIN TYPE ON TYPE.TYPE_ID = TENDER.TYPE_ID
LEFT JOIN ITEM ON ITEM.ITEM_ID = TENDER.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY TYPE_NAME, TENDER.ITEM_ID;
```

Comment: Hi I Tried Partition but group by Item_ID will duplicate Type_Name If I add another Sales with another Item_ID. Type Name should be Consolidated.. when adding another sales results to
     CASH
     CREDIT
     CASH

Answer (score 1):

Since the `service charge` is 10% of the `amount`, you don't really need to `join` to the `item` table.  Instead just multiply the `sum(amount)` by .1:

```
select TYPE_NAME, sum(AMOUNT) as Amount, sum(AMOUNT) * .1 as SC
from TENDER 
    LEFT JOIN TYPE ON TYPE.TYPE_ID = TENDER.TYPE_ID
GROUP BY TYPE_NAME
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/488ba/5)

---

Resulting in:

```
type_name   Amount  SC
Cash        600     60
Credit      500     50
```

Comment: but SC totals to 110 instead of 100

Comment: @FatalError -- 10% of 600+500 is 110... Your sample data doesn't appear to be correct... Something is still off, but this should get you close...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want this:

```
select ITEM.ITEM_ID, ServiceCharge,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_NAME = 'CASH' THEN Amount END) as Cash,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_NAME = 'CREDIT' THEN Amount END) as Credit
from TENDER LEFT JOIN
     TYPE
     ON TYPE.TYPE_ID = TENDER.TYPE_ID LEFT JOIN
     ITEM
     ON ITEM.ITEM_ID = TENDER.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY ITEM.ITEM_ID, ServiceCharge;
```

This puts the values into columns, so there is no duplication.

Comment: TypeName is Dynamic it's not fixed to cash or credit.

Answer (score 0):

I combined Slava Murygin and sandeep rawat answers, this give me proper results for succeeding sales.

Came up with this

```
 ;WITH SUMS AS (
 select TYPE_NAME, AMOUNT as Amount, 
 sum(ServiceCharge)/ (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TENDER.ITEM_ID) ) as SC 
 from TENDER 
 LEFT JOIN TYPE ON TYPE.TYPE_ID = TENDER.TYPE_ID
 LEFT JOIN ITEM ON ITEM.ITEM_ID = TENDER.ITEM_ID
 GROUP BY TYPE_NAME, TENDER.ITEM_ID, AMOUNT
 )
 Select Type_Name , Amount, Tender.ITEM_ID
 From Sums
 Group by TYPE_NAME
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Will this work for you. Please change the column name according to your convenience

```
SELECT 
    tender.item,typename,SUM(amount)as amount, SUM(Service_Charge/cntItem) as servercharge
FROM 
    woddb.TENDER_Table as Tender 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT item, count(item) as cntItem FROM woddb.Tender_Table GROUP BY ITEM) as cntTable
ON 
    Tender.item = cntTable.Item
LEFT JOIN
    woddb.TYPE_Table  as TYPETable 
ON 
    TYPETable.TYPEID = Tender.TYPEID
LEFT JOIN 
    woddb.ITEM_table as ITEMtable 
ON 
    ITEMtable.ITEM = Tender.ITEM
GROUP BY 
    tender.item,typename
```